# How to Integrate MathJax with Pjax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax, pjax

When I use Pjax I find MathJax cannot be loaded unless a manual refresh. I spent a lot of time on this. My solution for now is to add a js call in "pjax:end"

```
$.getScript("http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML");
```

However, it doesn't work...

I tried to monitor the timeline when a click is trigger in pjax, I found that only MathJax.js is called, while a manual refresh will get many other js stuff called.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz0Dp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx5Mz.png

(Sorry I don't have the permission yet to post imgs directly)

The first picture shows pjax refresh, and the second one shows a manual refresh.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation at http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html? EDIT. Let me re-phrase that: are you pulling in content on the fly? Do you have a live sample   page to look at?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).